# Sharepoint 2013 MobileExcelWebAccess Feature missing when creating subsite using a site template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, missing-features

I had a subsite in a site collection I wanted to transfer to another site collection (both in Sharepoint 2013). I made a site template with content out of it so I can transfer it to another site collection.  I uploaded the solution and activated it. I made sure the activated features were completely identical. However, when I create a new subsite and choose to use the uploaded solution, I continue to receive a error message saying it is missing a feature called "MobileExcelWebAccess."

I have no clue where to find that feature.  I literally enabled every site feature and site collection feature but I still end up with that error.  I've read on other resources that it could be found on Central Admin but I don't have access there.

If I can't enable it in the new site, is there a way to disable it in my old site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this from a SharePoint 2013 Management Shell: Enable-SPFeature MobileExcelWebAccess -Url http://[replace with your url]

Answer (score 0):

The simple line script from Ola Ekdahl did not work for me, but this did:

Replace the $url with your site collection url
save the script in .ps1 file
Open SharePoint Online Management Shell in Administrator mode and execute the script like .\
A prompt will be poped-up that asks your credential (Administrator) for the site collection

```
    $url = "https://<your site collection url>"
$clientDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$runtimeDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$cred = get-credential
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.username, $cred.password) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 
if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
$clientContext.Site.Features.Add('e995e28b-9ba8-4668-9933-cf5c146d7a9f',$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

source: http://mahedevelopment.blogspot.gr/2016/07/sharepoint-online-mobileexcelwebaccess.html